# Render Html select list based on data returned from ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4

I have a select list and I want to set the selected option based on the value from ajax call, but the select list is not appearing, but everything else will be rendered to the view. The problem is with my if-else statement. Is there a way I can set the selected option based on ajax value without if-else

**here is my javascript function:**

```
function FillUserTable() {


        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/GetAllUsers",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#EditUserDiv").css("display", "block");
                $("#MainPage").css("display", "none");
                $("#AllUsersTable2").dataTable().fnDestroy();
                $('#AllUsersTable2').DataTable({
                    paging: true,
                    processing: true, // control the processing indicator.
                    retrieve: true,
                    LengthMenu: false,
                    responsive: true,
                    aaData: data,
                    columns: [
                        { "data": "NationalID" ,"title": "هوية المستخدم" },
                        { "data": "username", "title": "اسم المستخدم" },
                        { "data": "FullName", "title": "الاسم" },
                        { "data": "MobileNumber","title": "رقم الهاتف" },
                        { "data": "Email","title": "البريد الالكتروني" },
                        { "data": "RoleName", "title": "صلاحية المستخدم" },
                        { "data": "IsActiveText", "title": "حالة المستخدم" },
                        {
                            data: null,
                            render: function (data, type, row) {
                                console.log(data.IsActive);
                                var htmlData= '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#a'+data.NationalID+'">عرض</button>'+
                                    '<div class="modal fade" id="a'+data.NationalID+'" tabindex = "-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">'+
                                        '<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">'+
                                            '<div class="modal-content">'+
                                                '<div class="modal-header">'+
                                                    '<h1 class="modal-title" id="test2" style="text-align: right;"> بيانات المستخدم</h1>'+
                                                    '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>'+
                                                '</div>' +

                                                '<div class="modal-body">' +
                                                        '<form action="" method="post">'+                                                                  
                                                                '<div class="row">' +
                                                                    '<div class="col-md-6">' +
                                                                        '<div class="form-group">' +
                                                                            '<label for="Email" class="control-label">البريد الإلكتروني</label>' +
                                                                            '<input type="text" id="Email' + data.NationalID + '" name="Email" value="' + data.Email + '" class="control-label"><br />' +
                                                                            '<label id="lblError'+data.NationalID+'" style="color:red;margin-right: -250px"></label>' +
                                                                        '</div >' +
                                                                    '</div >' 
                                                                    if (data.IsActive == 1) {
                                                                        htmlData = htmlData + '<div class="col-md-6">'
                                                                                                    '<div class="form-group">' +
                                                                                                        '<label for="IsActive" class="control-label">حالة المستخدم</label>' +
                                                                                                        '<select name="IsActive" id="IsActive' + data.NationalID + '">' +
                                                                                                            '<option  value="2">...</option>' +
                                                                                                            '<option selected value="1">نشط</option>' +
                                                                                                            '<option value="0">غير نشط</option>' +
                                                                                                        '</select>' +
                                                                                                    '</div >' +
                                                                                              '</div >'
                                                                    } else if (data.IsActive == 0) {
                                                                        htmlData = htmlData + '<div class="col-md-6">'
                                                                                                    '<div class="form-group">' +
                                                                                                        '<label for="IsActive" class="control-label">حالة المستخدم</label>' +
                                                                                                        '<select name="IsActive" id="IsActive' + data.NationalID + '">' +
                                                                                                            '<option  value="2">...</option>' +
                                                                                                            '<option value="1">نشط</option>' +
                                                                                                            '<option selected value="0">غير نشط</option>' +
                                                                                                        '</select>' +
                                                                                                   '</div >' +
                                                                                               '</div >'
                                                                    }
                                                                    else {
                                                                        htmlData = htmlData + '<div class="col-md-6">'
                                                                                                    '<div class="form-group">' +
                                                                                                        '<label for="IsActive" class="control-label">حالة المستخدم</label>' +
                                                                                                        '<select name="IsActive" id="IsActive' + data.NationalID + '">' +
                                                                                                            '<option  value="2">...</option>' +
                                                                                                            '<option value="1">نشط</option>' +
                                                                                                            '<option selected value="0">غير نشط</option>' +
                                                                                                        '</select>' +
                                                                                                   '</div >' +
                                                                                               '</div >'
                                                                    }
                                                                    htmlData = htmlData +  ' </div > ' +
                                                                                            '<div class="row">' +
                                                                                                '<div class="col-md-6">' +
                                                                                                        '<div class="form-group">' +
                                                                                                            '<label for="RoleId" class="control-label">صلاحية المستخدم</label>' +
                                                                                                                    '<select name="RoleId" id="RoleId' + data.NationalID + '">' +
                                                                                                                    '<option  value="0">...</option>' +
                                                                                                                    '<option value="1">رئيس جهة</option>' +
                                                                                                                    '<option value="2"> ممثل لجنة</option>' +
                                                                                                                    '<option value="3">رئيس أو موظف لجنة</option>' +
                                                                                                                    '<option value="4"> عضو لجنة</option>' +
                                                                                                                '</select>' +
                                                                                                        '</div >' +
                                                                                                '</div >' +
                                                                                            ' </div > ' +
                                                                                    '</form >'+
                                                                               '</div > ' +

                                                                                '<div class="modal-footer">'+
                                                                                    '<button id="close' + data.NationalID + '" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">إغلاق</button>'+
                                                                                    '<button type="button" onclick="UpdateUserBtn(' + data.NationalID + ')" class="btn btn-primary">تعديل المستخدم </button>'+
                                                                                '</div>'+
                                                                            '</div>'+
                                                                        '</div>'+
                                                                    '</div >'

                                return htmlData;

                            }
                        },
                    ],
                    });
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, thrownError) {
                e.preventDefault();

                $.notify(
                    "حدث خطأ أثناء تحميل البيانات, الرجاء المحاولة مرة أخرى",
                    {
                        globalPosition: 'top center',
                        className: 'error'
                    }
                );
            }
        });
    }
```

when I use `console.log(data.IsActive);` the values will be correct it is 0 or 1

Comment: This looks like a very awkward way to generate html. I think you would be better off manipulating the Document Object Model instead string building. If you must generate a string I would investigate template literals

Comment: In your case you can also use `'<option value="2" ' + (data.IsActive===2 ? 'selected' : '') + '>...</option>'` check the [ternary operator here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `if`, `else if` and `else` blocks for showing this select, each line like this:

`htmlData = htmlData + '<div class="col-md-6">'`

you miss a `+` operator at the end of it! so it's not adding the rest of your html code to the `htmlData`, just add these `+`s and it will work fine ...

However, I'd like to recommend you to re-restructure your code and have more small composed pieces instead of doing all of this in one place, also, when you create large strings on multiple lines, consider using (`) backticks instead of (' or ") quotations, it will enable you to get rid of all these `+`s